# PHP/MYSQL Count returning incorrect value

Tags: php, sql, count

I'm creating a function to check my database against a username and a password to return a value of true if it matches and false if not (I used some print values to give myself a visual aid). Now, the only fields in my database are id = 1, username = muyiwa, password = password (a SHA1 encrypted version, anyway). Anything else should throw an error of incorrect values or, in my specific case, line 22: print "no".

However, this doesn't seem to be the case. Here's the code:

```
function checkLoginName($username, $password) {
    global $mysqli;
    $username = sanitizeData($username);
    $password = SHA1($password);

    $sql = "SELECT COUNT(`id`) FROM `users` WHERE `username` = '$username' AND `password` = '$password'";
    $query = mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql) or die("Error: ".mysqli_error($mysqli));
    $rows = mysqli_num_rows($query);
    if ($rows == 1) {
        //return true;
        print "yes!";
    } else {
        //return false;
        print "no";
    }
}

checkLoginName("poo", "ha");
```

Just to verify, "poo" and "ha" should not return a value of "yes!" as they don't exist in the database, but it does! Everything else seems to work okay, I believe it's an SQL error of an error with my logic.

Comment: COUNT(*) will always return at least 1 row, change to `SELECT id FROM ...`

Comment: Take a print of `mysqli_fetch_array($query)`

Answer (score 3):

Your logic is wrong:

```
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(`id`) FROM `users` WHERE `username` = '$username' AND `password` = '$password'";
```

You are selecting `COUNT()` and that will always return one row in the result set.

In this case, you can just change it to:

```
$sql = "SELECT `id` FROM `users` WHERE `username` = '$username' AND `password` = '$password'";
```

Or you leave the query as it is, fetch your row and check for the value of `COUNT`.

Answer (score 1):

You're selecting `COUNT()`. This will **always return one row**.

You don't want to check `mysqli_num_rows`, since it will always be `1`. Instead you want to *fetch* the first column of the first result row, because that's your `COUNT` result.

Comment: How do I go about fetching the first column?

Comment: The way you always fetch results: `$row = mysqli_fetch_array($query); $row[0];` or something along those lines.

Answer (score 0):

Using `COUNT(*)` (or any aggregate) will always return *at least* 1 row.

You can wrap it like below to only return a row when there is a `COUNT` > 0.

```
SELECT * 
FROM   (SELECT Count(`id`) AS count 
        FROM   `users` 
        WHERE  `username` = '$username' 
               AND `password` = '$password') a
WHERE  a.count > 0
```